# Desenvolvendo aplicativos Android utilizando Python

Tags: android, python

É possível de criar aplicativos Android com a linguagem Python? 
Se sim, como funciona?

Comment: Caso não saiba como começar, é utilizando o framework Kivy, http://kivy.org Leia a documentação.

Answer (score 13):

Sim, é possível.

Uma vez eu vi uma discussão sobre isso na lista da infraestrutura do fedora, indicaram esta sdk: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android?source=c

Ela transforma um programa em Phyton em um apk. Usei muito pouco.

Segue um famoso HelloWorld:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.9')
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string('''
<HelloWorldScreen>:
    cols: 1
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome to the Hello world'
    Button:
        text: 'Click me! %d' % root.counter
        on_release: root.my_callback()
''')

class HelloWorldScreen(GridLayout):
    counter = NumericProperty(0)
    def my_callback(self):
        print 'The button have been pushed'
        self.counter += 1

class HelloWorldApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HelloWorldScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HelloWorldApp().run()
```

Basta usar o comando abaixo para gerar o apk.

```
./distribute.sh -m
```

Segue documentação completa (inglês): http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Putz cara, não suporto Java e por isso era resistente a desenvolver para Android. Obrigado. Agora vejo uma nova luz no fim desse túnel.

Comment: obrigado, foi muito útil saber que posso fazer app com python. estou iniciando nessa linguagem. muito obrigado!!!